# Qualtrics Import Survey - Python implementation of cURL

Tags: python, http, curl, qualtrics

I'm trying to write a function to import a survey into qualtrics using their V3 api. They've given the following in their documentation

```
curl -H 'X-API-TOKEN: yourapitoken' \
-F 'name=Test' \
-F 'file=@/path/to/MySurvey.qsf;type=application/vnd.qualtrics.survey.qsf' \
  'https://yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys'
```

I'm trying to implement this in python using the requests library.

I'm not quite sure how to pass the `'file=@/path/to/MySurvey.qsf;type=application/vnd.qualtrics.survey.qsf'` to `requests.get()`

Current setup:

```
headers = {'X-API-TOKEN':'xxxxxxxx'}
base_url = 'http://coN.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/'
files = [
       ('name','New Survey'),
       ('file', ......),
       ]
test = requests.get(base_url, headers, files)
```

What do I replace `.....` with to get this working?

Qualtrics API Documentation : https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-survey-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, i think you should send a post request .
Then you need `data` for the post data, and `files` for the file .

```
base_url = 'http://coN.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/'
headers = {'X-API-TOKEN':'xxxxxxxx'}
data = {'name':'New Survey'}
files = {'file':('File Name', open('File Path', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.qualtrics.survey.qsf') }
test = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)

print(test.status_code)
print(test.json())
```

In the `files` dict, 'File Name' is the name of the file, followed by the file object, and then the 'content_type' .  You will find more info in the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: Sadly, I was using a 'get' request (even thought the Qualtrics documentation says 'post').